# Can't assign a numpy array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm unable to assign a numpy array from a tuple of numpy arrays to a pandas dataframe. Can someone help me? I'm using a third party library to fetch the data and to produce the output numpy array.

Code:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import ccxt # crypto exchange library
import tulipy as ti # financial indicators

def currentTimeMillis(self):
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

currentMillisMinus250min  = currentTimeMillis() - 30000000

bitmex = ccxt.bitmex()

ohlcvDf = pd.DataFrame(
            bitmex.fetch_ohlcv(symbol="BTC/USD", limit=500, timeframe="1m", since=currentMillisMinus250min),
            columns = ["timestamp", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"])

macdNp = ti.macd(ohlcvDf["close"].to_numpy(), 12, 26, 9)

ohlcvDf["macd"] = macdNp[0]
ohlcvDf["signal"] = macdNp[1]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Tuple of ndarrays:

```
(
 array([ 6.68695914e+00,  6.12108219e+00,  5.64479926e+00,  4.94431782e+00,
         4.33794071e+00,  3.81237487e+00,  3.46875952e+00,  3.15956840e+00]), 
 array([ 6.68695914,   6.57378375,   6.38798685,   6.09925304,
         5.74699058,   5.36006744,   4.98180585,   4.61735836]),
 array([ 0.00000000e+00, -4.52701560e-01, -7.43187590e-01, -1.15493523e+00,
        -1.40904987e+00, -1.54769256e+00, -1.51304634e+00, -1.45778996e+00])
)
```

Comment: do you mean `numpy.array` or other array? please provide full example of your code

Comment: @Kobe Janssens please give the code used for generating tuple of arrays.

Comment: @Roim Yeah, I mean numpy arrays. I firstly didn't included the full code because I'm using some 3th party libraries. But I've updated my question this the full code (3th party libraries included).

Comment: @Snehil Okay, done

Comment: @KobeJanssens The code you provided is  not   completely helpful and giving error, If you have successfully generated the tuple **macdNp** , can you provide its length , After doing some modification in your code and reading docs of tulipy I got the length of tuple as **3**, and all 3 arrays in tuple is of shape **(496, )**. Can you verify it?

Comment: Yeah, When I print the length of the tuple it returns indeed 3.

Comment: Also , is this your complete code?

Comment: I'm doing some calculations on the first and the second numpy.array but I'm unable to select these. Despite of that, I'm able to print to full tuple of numpy arrays. I've also used another technical indicator but I hadn't with that one (ema) probably becaus that technical indicator only outputs 1 column (not in a tuple). Weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import ccxt # crypto exchange library
import tulipy as ti # financial indicators

def currentTimeMillis():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

currentMillisMinus250min  = currentTimeMillis() - 30000000

bitmex = ccxt.bitmex()

ohlcvDf = pd.DataFrame(
        bitmex.fetch_ohlcv(symbol="BTC/USD", limit=500, timeframe="1m", since=currentMillisMinus250min),
        columns = ["timestamp", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"])

macdNp = ti.macd(ohlcvDf["close"].to_numpy(), 12, 26, 9)

nan_arr = np.nan * np.ones(shape=(25,))
ohlcvDf["macd"] = np.append(nan_arr, macdNp[0])
ohlcvDf["signal"] = np.append(nan_arr, macdNp[1])
```

In your code you have used **self,self.macdPeriodFast, self.macdPeriodSlow, self.macdSignal**, without referencing it anywhere, Since I just read  about these library and tried to generate the tuple(which may not be same as yours). But I am able to generate the tuples and print these arrays.

Can you provide anything else that you used in this particular code!

I have read about library  [here](https://openwritings.net/pg/python-draw-macd-using-tulip-indicators-matplotlib)

Comment: Yeah, sorry my code wasn't the best. I've updated the code and I think I misunderstood the error. The error appars when I declare the first and second column to a new ohlcvDf column.

Comment: @KobeJanssens the thing is **ohlcvDf** is of length **500**, and every array **macdNp[0],  macdNp[1],  macdNp[2]** is of lenght **475**

Comment: Oow, I think this is because the first 26 values would normally be NaN, because this function needs the 26 previous values to calculate the output. (macdPeriodSlow = 26)

Comment: You desire an upvote! Thank you very much for the patience!

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can add 26 None values at the beginning of the numpy array?

Comment: yeah so you want to add 26 np.nan values to all these three arrays?

Comment: Indeed, at the beginning of each array.

Comment: @KobeJanssens check my edit, I have not modified arrays, yet done the thing that was needed, does that work for you?

Answer (score -2):

better way is to use np.array instead of just array.

```
import numpy as np

arrays = (
 np.array([ 6.68695914e+00,  6.12108219e+00,  5.64479926e+00,  4.94431782e+00,
         4.33794071e+00,  3.81237487e+00,  3.46875952e+00,  3.15956840e+00]), 
 np.array([ 6.68695914,   6.57378375,   6.38798685,   6.09925304,
         5.74699058,   5.36006744,   4.98180585,   4.61735836]),
 np.array([ 0.00000000e+00, -4.52701560e-01, -7.43187590e-01, -1.15493523e+00,
        -1.40904987e+00, -1.54769256e+00, -1.51304634e+00, -1.45778996e+00])
)

print(arrays[0])
```

Output:

```
[6.68695914 6.12108219 5.64479926 4.94431782 4.33794071 3.81237487
 3.46875952 3.1595684 ]
```